# What kind of lightbulb is this?

Tags: lighting, bulb

[image]

I need to replace a burnt out bulb in my rental unit, but I have no clue what type of bulb this is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a J-type halogen bulb.

Compare with this: [http://www.amazon.com/Type-120v-Halogen-Anyray-brand/dp/B00520MXKS](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00520MXKS)

Comment: Pretty sure you're right. I did some more searching on j type and found some close matches. Thanks.